# Ruby on Rails 3 - Serialize Array Mismatched Class Bafflement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, serialization, activerecord

Hey there,
I am baffled by this serialization mismatch problem in Rails 3.0.5 and Ruby 1.9.2.  I am seeding the database with a subclass of Array and then trying to save to an ActiveRecord object.  Can anyone please help me?  I was initially trying to serialize as Graph but reduced it to Array to avoid bugs with the custom class.  I am very stumped as this doesn't make intuitive sense to me.  Thank you very much for your help!

```
class Graph < Array
  ..

class Settings < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :graphs, Array
  ..
```

Very last lines in seeds.rb -- eg nothing happens after.  Just saving a lot for debugging purposes:

```
  sh_1g = sh_1g.to_a
  d.company.settings.add_graph(sh_1g.to_a)
  d.company.settings.save!
  d.company.save!  
  d.save!
  if sh_1g == d.company.settings.graphs[0]
    puts "the added graph matches the first graph in the graphs array"
  end
  puts "added " + sh_1g.inspect + " to " + d.company.settings.graphs.inspect
  puts "class of added graph as saved is" + d.company.settings.graphs[0].class.inspect
  puts "class of added graph is " + sh_1g.class.inspect
  puts "class of graphs serial is " + d.company.settings.graphs.class.inspect
```

Output of seeds.rb puts as it is run:

```
the added graph matches the first graph in the graphs array
added [[[0, 0, ..]]] to to [[[[0, 0, ..]]]..]
class of added graph as saved isArray
class of added graph is Array
class of graphs serial is Array
```

However, in console:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > Company.all[1].settings
ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch: graphs was supposed to be a Array, but was a String
    from /Users/dlipa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:106:in `unserialize_attribute'
    from /Users/dlipa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:82:in `read_attribute'
    from /Users/dlipa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1586:in `attribute_for_inspect'
    from /Users/dlipa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1667:in `block in inspect'
    from /Users/dlipa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1665:in `collect'
    from /Users/dlipa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1665:in `inspect'
    from /Users/dlipa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:146:in `inspect'
    from /Users/dlipa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /Users/dlipa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/dlipa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Weird observation -- if I run this code from the console there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a problem similar to this one. My problem stemmed from the placement of my `serialize :some_column, Array` statement. If by some chance the attribute methods on your ActiveRecord object class get defined before you call `serialize`, you will not have the setter and getter methods properly defined.

So, I would make sure that the `define_attribute_methods` is not being called on your Settings class before you declare which columns are serialized.

Answer (score 0):

set option

```
:null => true
```

in your migration for the field "graphs". It fixes this error