# String to Serialized Array? (nr. 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, serialization, activerecord

i'm trying to add an before filter to manipulate user input:

```
class FormField < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :field_type, :name, :field_options
  serialize :field_options, Array
  before_validation :update_field_options

  def update_field_options
    begin
        self.field_options = self.field_options.split(/\,/).map(&:strip)
      rescue ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch
        errors.add_to_base("Die Optionen bitte mit Kommata trennen)")
        false
    end
  end
end
```

when i try to create a record with "1,2,3" it does not work (ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch).

migration is:

```
t.string :field_options, :null => true
```

not sure what i do wrong here. if i change the before filter to:

```
self.field_options = [1,2,3]
```

it works, it seems that i can't access the self.field_options, but i can set them.....

```
logger.warn { "field_options #{ self.field_options }" }
```

does not output anything, not even "field_options", self gives me:

similar to:

[String to Serialized Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711334/string-to-serialized-array)

[Ruby on Rails 3 - Serialize Array Mismatched Class Bafflement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156900/ruby-on-rails-3-serialize-array-mismatched-class-bafflement)

LOG:

```
Started POST "/global/form_fields?format=" for 127.0.0.1 at Sun Mar 20 17:50:00 +0100 2011
  SQL (3.8ms)  describe `shift_categories_users`
  SQL (3.9ms)  describe `roles_users`
  Processing by Global::FormFieldsController#create as 
  Parameters: {"form_field"=>{"name"=>"rails verion", "field_options"=>"1,2,3", "field_type"=>"select"}, "commit"=>"Create Form field", "authenticity_token"=>"nTmPr1H3Ilp6eRqLq/9Gd0JZx7wAw0lHqGlMBEq74HU=", "utf8"=>"✓"}
  User Load (5.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 261 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.9ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
  Account Load (1.6ms)  SELECT `accounts`.* FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`subdomain` = 'expertcloud' LIMIT 1
  ConfigOption Load (1.8ms)  SELECT `config_options`.* FROM `config_options` WHERE `config_options`.`name` = 'headline' AND (`config_options`.account_id = 82) LIMIT 1
DEPRIATION WARNING - make sure you use it in the correct context. user.admin? use user.role?(:admin) insted
DEPRIATION WARNING - make sure you use it in the correct context. user.admin? use user.role?(:admin) insted
  SQL (3.1ms)  describe `roles_users`
  Role Load (2.0ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles`
  Role Load (2.0ms)  SELECT * FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `roles_users` ON `roles`.id = `roles_users`.role_id WHERE (`roles_users`.user_id = 261 ) LIMIT 1
Rendered shared/_options.html.haml (73.3ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `config_options`.* FROM `config_options` WHERE `config_options`.`name` = 'headline' AND (`config_options`.account_id = 82) LIMIT 1
  Role Load (1.2ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `roles_users` ON `roles`.id = `roles_users`.role_id WHERE `roles`.`name` = 'admin' AND (`roles_users`.user_id = 261 ) LIMIT 1
  SQL (2.9ms)  describe `shift_categories_users`
  Plan Load (1.8ms)  SELECT `plans`.* FROM `plans` WHERE `plans`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
Rendered shared/_navigation.html.haml (179.3ms)
Rendered shared/_header.html.haml (269.9ms)
Rendered shared/_footer.html.haml (1.1ms)
Rendered global/form_fields/new.html.haml within layouts/application (1141.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1354ms (Views: 1231.8ms | ActiveRecord: 33.0ms)
```

**EDIT**
in the console:

```
 FormField.create!(:field_options => "1,2,3")
```

and if i try to debug it in the model with:

```
puts "SPLIT #{ self.field_options }"
puts "SPLIT #{ self.inspect }"
```

the error appears during reading the **self.field_options** (which is "1,2,3")

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.. Just taking a stab at this, maybe your field_options should be of type binary instead of string

```
t.binary :field_options, :null => true
```

Comment: mh, no i still get: _FormField.create!(:field_options => "1,2,3")_

**SPLIT #<FormField id: nil, field_type: nil, name: nil, field_options: "1,2,3", value: nil, position: nil, formable_id: nil, formable_type: nil, account_form_field_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>**

_ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch: field_options was supposed to be a Array, but was a String_

Comment: but the error throws if i try to access *self.field_options" in the before_validation callback with: _puts self.field_options_ so it might sth happend during reading .. ?

Comment: yeah I think so. try FormField.create!(:field_options => [1,2,3]) and see what happens?

Comment: that works as expected: **=> #<FormField id: 34, field_options: [1, 2, 3], .... >**  (had to add "if self.field_options.is_a?(String)" to before_validation

Comment: still don't get why it throws the error in the read progress. i guess i have to do it in the controller, splitting up the string to an ruby Array.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring that field_options must inherit from an array.

```
serialize :field_options, Array
```

When you assign an array to field_options, it serializes the data for you (in yaml, but this should be transparent to you.)

you can't:

```
self.field_options = "any string"
```

because strings aren't arrays. If you must pre-process a user-input string, you'll need to

```
attr_accessible :field_options_str # Rails mass-assign
attr_accessor   :field_options_str # Ruby

def update_field_options
  self.field_options = self.field_options_str.split(/\,/).map(&:strip)
  # I had to…
  # field_options = field_options_str.split(',').map &:strip
end
```

You could also,

```
serialize :field_options # remove Array
```

Then, rails would serialize your string as a yaml string, and self.field_options would unserialize it to a ruby string, allowing you to split and map it, and store the resulting array.